# How to pass function as an argument, and force this function to use index values from outer loop in Python?

Tags: python, scope

Let's say I have a function below, which works fine:

```
P = [1,2,3,4]

def run(P,
        mode = '1'):

    for x,n in list(enumerate(P)):

        if P[x] > 1:

            for y,i in list(enumerate(P)):

                if P[y] > 2:

                    if mode == '1':
                        prob = P[x] # line A
                        print(prob)
    return P

run(P)
```

Output:

```
2
2
3
3
4
4
Out[231]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now I want to add inner function f instead of "line A"

```
def run(P,
        mode = '1'):

    for x,n in list(enumerate(P)):

        if P[x] > 1:

            for y,i in list(enumerate(P)):

                if P[y] > 2:

                    if mode == '1':
                        #prob = P[x] # line A
                        # Inner function
                        def f():
                            prob = P[x]
                            return prob

                        prob = f()
                        print(prob)
    return P



run(P,
    mode = '1')
```

Still works fine.

Now I want to build a python package and allow people to pass their own function
as an argument in function f place.

## Solution with global function:

```
def run(P,
        f,
        mode = '1'):
    global x     
    for x,n in list(enumerate(P)):

        if P[x] > 1:

            for y,i in list(enumerate(P)):

                if P[y] > 2:

                    if mode == '1':
                        #prob = P[x]
                        prob = f()
                        print(prob)
                        #prob = custom_kernel()
    return P


def f():
    prob = P[x]
    return prob


run(P,
    f=f,
    mode = '1')
```

Works fine, but global environment shouldn't be contaminated. Alternatively we may just declare global x function and later delete in the end of "run" function, but it still implies interference with global environment.

When I will not use global function declaration, I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

How to pass function as an argument, and force this function to work with "x" indices, which would be encapsulated in scope of "run" function?

How to force "f" function to use "run" function scope state from proper moments, while x indices changes dynamically?

Does static scope feature in Python prevent such action?

Comment: On what line you are getting `NameError`? Always add full error log

Comment: Problem is solved now, but I will try to post more complete question description next time, thank you for your tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have `x` accepted as a parameter of `f`:

```
def f(x):  # Make it a parameter
   . . .

. . .

prob = f(x)  # Then pass that info in inside of run
print(prob)
```

`f` is just a function. It can accept arguments just like any other function.

Comment: Thanks! now it looks so simple.. I think I was trying before to add "x" to f() in code where I was invoking run() function instead of put it directly in run() function body and because of that it didn't work.